# sample size to estimate mean of zero modified log normal variable

Tags: sample-size, lognormal-distribution, zero-inflation

I would like to estimate the average value of a variable "A" in a population. I think only 5% of the population has a figure of A > 0, 95% has A = 0. Using a previous non random sample, I believe the distribution of A (when its >0) is lognormal.

How do I calculate an appropriate sample size to estimate the average value of A with an acceptable level of error? I could calculate the required sample size to estimate the average value of A when A > 0 then divide by the p(A)  but this could lead to a very large sample size.

Do I use the variance of a zero modified log normal given by (I think [1](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/EnvStats/html/ZeroModifiedLognormal.html))

Var[log(Y)] = (1 - p) σ^2 + p (1-p) μ^2

and then apply a typical sample size calculation?

Comment: It might depend on what you mean by "level of error."  If that means "with a standard error not to exceed such-and-such," then the distribution is of little import.  If instead it means something more refined, such as limiting the chance that the estimate differ from the true value by more than such-and-such, then it looks like you are asking for a way to construct a good *confidence interval* for the mean of a "delta-lognormal" distribution. (The sample size determination depends on these distinctions.)

Comment: Hi Whuber, I am looking to create a confidence interval for the mean which is some acceptable width.  Thanks for 'delta-lognormal' hint. I have found a paper to determine the 95% confidence interval for the delta lognormal but unsure about how to get a sample size from that. thanks

Comment: Could I simulate the required sample number by using the results from my non random sample I already have, adding extra instances of where A=0 so the P(A) is about 0.05 then take many different sized samples from this pretend population. I could determine the average size of the confidence interval and whether the proportion of times the true mean fell within the confidence interval. I could plot that by the sample size.

Comment: A better way begins with the formula you are using for the confidence interval.  (There are several possibilities.)  That formula will depend on (1) your guess about the proportion of zeros, (2) your guess about the geometric mean and geometric standard deviation of the nonzero values, and (3) the sample size $n$.  You can solve for $n$ in terms of the other values and the maximal allowable width of the interval--that's just a matter of algebra.  If you wish, you could then verify your solution by means of a simulation.  That will spare you the need to run many simulations for different $n$.